# Using regex to replace all sets of phrases with the last phrase?

Tags: java, regex, wikipedia

I have a string like `'''Coffee''' is a [[Drip brew|brewed]] [[beverage]] prepared from the roasted seeds of several species of an evergreen`. I need to replace each `[[something]]` simply with `something` and if the there is more than one "phrase" such as `[[Drip brew|brewed]]`, I would like to replace that set with the **last** (not necessarily second) phrase such as `brewed` in this example. Is there a clean way to do this using RegEx? I am trying to clean up some JSON from Wikipedia for some esoteric purposes.

Comment: Have you tried [JWPL](https://code.google.com/p/jwpl/)? It's an entire MediaWiki parser that will handle such things for you.

Comment: I haven't, but I am looking at it right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string.replaceAll("\\[\\[([^]]*[|])?([^]]*?)\\]\\]", "$2");
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work. It replaces what I want with a `2`. Here is the output I'm getting `'''Coffee''' is a 2 2 prepared from the roasted seeds of several species of an evergreen`

Comment: Perfect, that works. 

Note to anyone else: the `2` corresponds to the last group because something like `"[[a|b|c|d]]".replaceAll("\\[\\[([^]]*[|])?([^]]*?)\\]\\]", "$2");` produces the desired result `d`.

Comment: @ijkilchenko - heh, sorry about that.  so many different regex syntaxes (got my perl mixed with my java).